# psycopg2.extras.DictCursor not returning dict in postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Im using psycopg2 to access postgres database using the below query. In order to return a dictionary from the executed query, im using DictCursor in my cursor but still my output is a list and not a dictonary.

Here is the program and output below.

```
import psycopg2.extras

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect("user='postgres' host='localhost' password='postgres'",
                            )
except:
    print "I am unable to connect to the database"

cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)

cur.execute("""SELECT datname from pg_database""")


rows = cur.fetchall()
print "\nShow me the databases:\n"
print rows
```

Output:-

```
[['template1'], ['template0'], ['postgres'], ['iip'], ['test'], ['test_postgres'], ['testdb']]
```

Answer (score 8):

It looks like a list, smells like a list, but it's a [DictRow](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.DictRow).

```
rows = cur.fetchall()
for row in rows :
    print(type(row))

#>>> <class 'psycopg2.extras.DictRow'>
```

This means that you can still use the column names as keys to access the data :

```
rows = cur.fetchall()
print([row['datname'] for row in rows])
```

---

[This class](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/blob/master/lib/extras.py#L159) inherits directly from the builtin`list`  and add all the needed methods to implement a dictionary logic, but it doesn't change the representation `__repr__` or `__str__`, so the output is the same as a list.

> ```
> class DictRow(list):
>     """A row object that allow by-column-name access to data."""
> ```

---

`fetchall()` packs all the queried rows in a list without specifying the exact type.

Btw, maybe you are looking for this kind of cursor : [RealDictCursor](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#real-dictionary-cursor) ?

Comment: [`RealDictCursor`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#real-dictionary-cursor) is great, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For those who came where because they really like the easy reference of the dictionary for column:value record representation, the answer by PRMoureu which notes that the [DictRow](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/blob/master/lib/extras.py#L159) has all the usual dictionary logic means that you can iterate over the DictRow with .items() and get the key:value pairs.

```
rows = cur.fetchall()
row_dict = [{k:v for k, v in record.items()} for record in rows]
```

Will turn your list of DictRow records into a list of dict records.

Comment: AFAICT `row_dict = [{k: record[k] for k in record} for record in rows]` will _not_ work.